# cURL and redirects - returning multiple headers?

Tags: php, regex, redirect, curl

I'm writing a specialized PHP proxy and got stumped by a feature of cURL.

If the following values are set:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
```

cURL correctly handles redirects, but returns ALL page headers, not just the final (non-redirect) page, e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://otherpage
Set-Cookie: someCookie=foo
Content-Length: 198

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3241

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
...rest of content
```

Note that CURLOPT_HEADER is set because I need to read and copy parts of the original header into my proxy header.

I appreciate why it's returning all these headers (for example, my proxy code must detect any cookies set in the 302 header and pass them along). HOWEVER, it also makes it impossible to detect when the headers end and the content begins. Normally, with one header we could just do a simple split:

```
$split = preg_split('/\r\n\r\n/', $fullPage, 2)
```

But that obviously won't work here. Hm. We could try something that only splits if it looks like the next line is part of a header:

```
$split = preg_split('/\r\n\r\nHTML\/(1\.0|1\.1) \\d+ \\w+/', $fullPage)
// matches patterns such a "\r\n\r\nHTML/1.1 302 Found"
```

Which will work almost all the time, but chokes if someone has the following in their page:

```
...and for all you readers out there, here is an example HTTP header:
<PRE>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

BALLS!

We really want the split to **stop matching** as soon as it encounters any pattern of `\r\n\r\n` that isn't immediately followed by `HTML/1.x` - is there a way to do this with PHP RegExs? Even this solution can choke on the (quite rare) situation where someone puts an HTTP header right at the beginning of their content. Is there a way in cURL to get all of the returned pages as an array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the information of the total header size, and split the string up like this:

```
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$header_size = $curl_info["header_size"];
$header = substr($buffer, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($buffer, $header_size)
```

Information taken from [the helpful post by "grandpa"](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=474585).

Comment: great suggestion, I've been wondering about this and I've just checked for the next few headers every time I get a known http status that's likely not the last.

Comment: $body = substr($buffer, $header_size + 1) => This will remove the first character of the body. substr($buffer, $header_size) is correct

Comment: @Claude: Thanks for the correction!  Edited to reflect it.  Feel free to hit the button to suggest a change to answers when you see mistakes like this; that way, even if the author is long gone, mods can implement the corrections.

Comment: This won't work when the previous pages (redirect hops) return a response body along with the http 301/302 header. Example: [http://www.moebel.de/dekoration/pflanzen/kunstpflanzen], [http://www.delta.com/skymiles/manage_account/skymiles_pin/index.jsp]

Answer (score 1):

use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);`

TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).

Comment: Sorry i just wanted to mention the importance

Answer (score 0):

```
$header_size = $curl_info["header_size"];
$header = substr($buffer, 0, $header_size-1);
$body = substr($buffer, $header_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add, to curl configurations:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:"));
```

It's will be resolve the problem.