# PHP curl how to retrieve headers when using Proxy. CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm connecting to a site using a proxy like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec ($curl);
```

Problem is that `CURLOPT_HEADER` is returning the headers from the proxy connection whereas I need the headers from the actual request to the URL. I believe the solution involves using `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` but I don't understand how to use it.

I tried this (taken from elsewhere on SO):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "HandleHeaderLine");
```

using function:

```
function HandleHeaderLine($curl, $header_line ) {
    echo "<br>YEAH: ".$header_line; // or do whatever
    return strlen($header_line);
}
```

But it seems I can only return the number of bytes. I'm unsure how to get the actual value. In my situation I just want the `Location` Header.

Thank you.

Comment: Is curl returning **only** the proxy header, or **all** headers? Because if it's the first, it can be something with your proxy configs that may be suppressing such info (I don't think how, since browser needs them), and if second, you have just to process the string headers it returns ([see it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017911/curl-and-redirects-returning-multiple-headers)).

Comment: Curl is definitely retrieving All the headers. I could see it when I enable `verbose`. The problem is that  `CURLOPT_HEADER ` only returns the proxy headers so I cannot use it to retrieve the `Location` header

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous callback for `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` will need access to the variable in which you want to store the header information. There are a few different approaches, but here some examples:

Using `use`:

```
$headers = [];
...
function HandleHeaderLine($curl, $header_line) use (&$headers)
{
    ...
    if ($isHeaderIWant) {
        $header[] = 'some info';
    }
    return strlen($header_line);
}
```

Using class property:

```
private $headers = [];
...
function HandleHeaderLine($curl, $header_line)
{
    ...
    if ($isHeaderIWant) {
        $this->header[] = 'some info';
    }
    return strlen($header_line);
}
```